# every gnome shell themes I use - renders the search unusable

Tags: gnome, themes, gnome-shell-extension

I've downloaded the gnome-shell theme extention. Using the default theme has no problem, but as soon as I try using one of the themes, clicking the "windows" key, then writing something to start searching for it, and the X server gets stuck.
I'm using Ubuntu 10.11, with gnome shell verion 3.2.2
Thanks for your help
Yair

Comment: Please update your question correct some local language "yair". strictly English recommended .

Comment: Which Version of gnome themes u use

Comment: Are you using any proprietary driver (ATI/AMD or Nvidia) ? Because I'm on Ubuntu Oneiric (gnome 3.2.2.1), currently using the gnome-shell theme extension and I see no crash on the X server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gaurav_Java already said, there is no fix as it is right now! This problem started with Gnome-Shell v3.2 and is mostly related to Nvidia drivers.

You can install this [Shell-extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/203/disable-search/), called "Disable Search", which does not resolve the problem itself, but simply disables the search function and therefore the crashes of X server (meaning: you don't have to force your machine to reboot every time).

Hopefully there will be a fix soon!

Answer (score 1):

This is not the FIX soution for this . u must try restarting shell to do following do this:

- Alt+F2
- type `'r'` and press return
- Even if the alt+f2 dialog doesn't show, it will still take your
  command and run it.

this will help u restarting shell . may be this would help

Comment: Nope. Tried it, and I also tried full restart.